# Wav File As Frequency Image

Tags: java, audio

I want to show a wav file as an image, so the frequency is charted on screen like you would see in a wav editor. Any ideas?

Comment: Use an AudioInputStream to read the data from the wAV file, then compute the FFT of that data and plot it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062968/display-sound-wav-mp3-as-graph-in-java

Comment: The above link is referring to audio display with no frequencies but the wave form. The question is a bit confusing in that respect. Most wave editors(!) actually show the wave form, but if you want to see frequencies(!) it's a slightly different topic.

Answer (score 5):

This is a rough answer, you have to investigate a little more with these keywords...First you need an **FFT-function** ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFT ), I'd suggest you try to find a lib or source-code, no need to reinvent the wheel. Then you apply that FFT-function to a **moving window**. So:

1. take n-samples from your wav-file
2. converts them using the FFT-function,
3. convert the fft-values to absolute values (that's the **spectrum**)
4. moves on m-samples
5. go back to 1.

In the end each window stands for a x-value (time), and the values of the spectrum represent the y-value (frequencies). That way you have your image.

I hope this is half-way understandable. It's hard to explain with just a few words. Good luck. :-)

Comment: I would suggest you DEFINITELY don't reinvent the wheel. FFTs are a solved problem. Don't even bother trying, you won't get it right the first time and spend all of you time debugging the FFT instead of writing your snazzy display. I suggest this library: http://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms

Comment: @basszero: Thanks for the link. Can you tell me though if I can use the binary API-version of "JTransforms" without showing any source code to anybody? I already try to find an answer somewhere else, only left with confusion... :-/

Comment: IANAL but here goes my best guess. The library I linked is licensed under the MPL/LGPL/GPL tri-license. Assuming you get to choose, LGPL allows you to use the library without having to make your application disclose source.

Comment: AudioDroid really nice answer ! Even though I'm not sure it answers the question (I think the OP meant "the waveform"), it's very interesting to read, so I still upvote !

Answer (score 0):

See [Chapter 10 Page 379](http://books.google.com/books?id=oNbFfcyAtv4C&pg=PP1&dq=swing+hacks#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Swing Hacks for an example.

Note it doesn't display the frequencies in the signal. You probably want to draw the amplitude of an audio signal, as an wav-editor would do.

Comment: The above link is referring to audio display with no frequencies but the wave form. The question is a bit confusing in that respect. Most wave editors(!) actually show the wave form, but if you want to see frequencies(!) it's a slightly different topic.

Comment: @AutoDroid (+1) I agree ,but ".. charted on screen like you would see in a wav editor" made me belive that he meant wave form instead of frequency.

Comment: @stacker : +1. If you just change the word "frequency" his whole question makes sense ;)