# Java libraries to determine voice note in wav file

Tags: java, waveform, voice-recording

Is any library written in java to determine voice note in wav file,

illustration: I record my voice then result the wav file, then I can know what is the note my voice.

This [website](http://www.seventhstring.com/tuner/tuner.html) has implemented this scenario:

Answer (score 1):

You may need to throw together your own custom class for that. I looked around and couldn't find any libraries specifically for that purpose, but creating your own shouldn't be to hard.

Here is a list of the frequencies for different musical notes:
http://www.seventhstring.com/resources/notefrequencies.html

You could create a class that uses these numbers and compares the sound to each frequency to see which it is.

Turning the wav file input to frequencies will require a FFT. Here is a link to a question that explains how to do just that.
[Wav File As Frequency Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214214/wav-file-as-frequency-image)

Comment: hi calderonmluis,how I can get frequency from wav file?

Comment: If I have resolved your question please mark my answer as the correct answer. Thanks