# Need to convert an mp3 file information to the graphical drawing of wave forms using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mp3

I was trying to do a personal project where I could visualize the waveforms of an mp3 file and visualize it in a JPanel but I am extremely new to GUI. I found a post that was answered nearly 14 years ago and the answer happened to be the book that I had been reading on how to do it. I hit a massive wall where I can't seem to figure out what to do to draw these waves and this is where I am turning for help.

The original SO question: [Display sound (.wav/.mp3) as graph in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062968/display-sound-wav-mp3-as-graph-in-java)

The book: https://archive.org/details/swinghacks0000mari/page/386/mode/2up  (Chapter 10: Building an Audio Waveform Display)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which part of that question do you want us to try and answer?  Extracting the audio frequency from a MP3 file?  Visualising a data set graphically?  I'm sure there are some more steps in there, but you need to narrow the questions down

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066698/gui-freezes-when-drawing-wave-from-animation-on-jpanel-though-i-used-swing-timer/12066748#12066748); [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517265/graphing-wav-file-in-java/27517678#27517678)

Comment: Also consider this JavaFX [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54927406/230513).

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am looking to visualize the waveforms much like your first example. I will try to get around to seeing If I can work it out myself, thank you for giving me a better resource to see what I'm needing to do next!